# Подтверждение data-confirm вызывается 2 раза

Tags: php, yii2

Перед сохранением хотел сделать подтверждение, прописал `data-confirm` и теперь окно вызывается 2 раза перед отправкой формы

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin()?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput() ?>        
<?= Html::submitButton('Сохранить', ['data-confirm' => 'Точно Сохранить'])?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

В чем может быть проблема, или это баг?

Answer (score 0):

По-видимому, у Вас установлена не совсем свежая версии yii2, так как такой баг уже давно заведен и пофикшен.
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/commit/3abc07d16cb4f877cdff9e24d97269345a6c8b44

Попробуйте обновиться до более новой версии фреймворка.

Comment: у меня как раз таки свежая версия `yii-basic-app-2.0.10`